# Не стоит ли Православным писать "мафематика", "феатр", "феория" и т.п.?

Tags: орфография, старая-орфография, греческий

Переформулирую этот вопрос: [Может ли православный передавать греческую "тету" как "т"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/464450) (вообще, если [непонятно](https://rus.stackexchange.com/posts/464450/timeline), то надо спрашивать тех, кому понятно)

Искони наш великий и могучий язык был связан неразрывными узами с византийской религиозной традицией. Известно, что если в старогреческом языке произношение "теты" более походило на "т"(что и переняли латиняне), то в новогреческом языке случился так называемый Th-fronting, т.е. "тету" стали произность с "фыканием". Это явление нашло своё отображение в таких исконных словах как Фёдор(Ѳедоръ), а не "Теодор" и подобных.

Тогда является ли такое слово как "математика", а не мафематика исконно русским? Не кафолическое ли это иезуитское извращение над Православным русским языком? Не начнём ли мы говоря "театр", а не "феатр" говорить также и "тотоаппарат" вместо русского слова фотоаппарат?

Comment: Закрытие вопроса -- надуманное. Во-первых, есть уже один достаточно аргументированный ответ. Во-вторых, "непонятно" -- это не аргумент. По крайней мере, для Православных. Например, суть вопроса по нейрохирургии мне тоже может показаться непонятной, однако это ещё не значит, что вопрос должен быть закрыт. Т.е. возможно, этот вопрос просто не для теж юзеров, которые его закрыли...

Answer (score 1):

1. Чтобы делать выводы, надо хорошо разбираться **в истории буквы Ф,** а это (даже на первый взгляд) очень сложная тема – предмет серьезных **лингвистических исследований**.

В русском языке были проведены **две реформы алфавита:** Ферт (Ф) и фита (Ѳ) — Пётр I в 1707—1708 годах отменил было ферт Ф (оставив фиту Ѳ), но вернул в 1710 году, восстановив церковнославянские правила употребления этих букв; фита отменена реформой 1917—1918 годов.

2. **История буквы Ф**: https://bash.news/sputnik/uroki-russkogo/110592-tragicheskaya-istoriya-bukvy-f

Когда-то давно было две буквы, которыми обозначали звук «ф»: «фита» и «ферт». Они пришли к нам из греческого языка.«Фита» (или «тэта») использовалась для заимствованных слов, обозначала звук «тх», а «ферт» для своих, а звук был – «пх». Путаница была еще та, поэтому «фиту» взяли и исключили из употребления.

Так в алфавите остался один «ферт». Даже выражение такое гуляло в народе: «ходить фертом». Так говорили про людей, которые любили упереть "руки в боки" и лопаться от важности. Значение фразеологизма: быть самодовольным, смотреть на людей свысока.

3. Существуют разные традиции, и русский алфавит можно считать **современной светской традицией.** Возможно, православная традиция другая,  но тогда в этой области нужно использовать **особый  алфавит**. Мы сейчас слышим вполне определенный звук (фонему) Ф, который обозначается буквой Ф, другие варианты **произношения** ушли в историю. Поэтому математика останется математикой, а физика физикой.
4. **Математика**  (из этимологического словаря Фасмера)

Происходит от др.-греч. μαθηματική «математика, астрология», далее из μαθεῖν «изучить», инф. аор. от μανθάνω – «учиться, изучать», из праиндоевр. *mn-, *men-, *mnā – «думать, мнить». Русск. математика заимств. через польск. matematyka или лат. mathematica (ars). Впервые фиксируется в неукоренившейся форме «мафиматика»  (источник 1672 года), в современной форме с 1699.

5. **Другие материалы по теме** (их очень много):

Как появилась буква «ф» в русском языке https://www.sinykova.ru/kak-poyavilas-bukva-f-v-russkom-yazyke/

Откуда у нас буква Ф https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5b33267990cdf400a9227292/otkuda-u-nas-bukva-f-5dd93c6321cd6d24351d7cce